# Double hash (#) in template

Tags: velocity

In an Apache Velocity template, double hashtag (i.e. `##`) means comment, but I want to add `##` literals into the template. How can I do that?

The reason is that I want to make a template for Github wiki, and the template includes `h2`'s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research I found this:

```
#set ( $double_hash = '##' )

${double_hash}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've even double the stuff in my jira release template that produce markdown...

```
#set ( $simple_hash = '#' )
#set ( $double_hash = '##' )
```

Thx for the hint !!

Comment: What is the additional insight you provide on top of the existing, upvoted and accepted answer? I do not get it.

Answer (score 1):

At least in velocity version 1.7 you can place 'unparsed content' in your template. Put it between `#[[` and `]]#`

Template example:

```
some text...
wont be parsed -> #[[${bla "#.#" #set{a="b" ###]]## <-wont be parsed
more text
```

Apache documentation can be found [here](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/vtl-reference.html#unparsed-content)